# Junk values from an input file in C

Tags: c, input, io, command-line-arguments

So I have this bit of C code below. When I place `printf` statements to test the text from the input file, I see that I'm getting a bunch of junk values, to be more specific they are not even alphabetic or numerical, I think they are diamonds with question marks in them.  I assume this means it is not processing these values the way it should be.  The input file a bit of MIPS assembly code, but in this context it is only a text file.  I have commented out all other parts of my program and am left with this small piece and yet I still receive the bad values.  What could I possibly be doing wrong here?

The command I use to run the program on the console is:

./assembler -symbols adder.asm

```
Where ./assembler is the driver    (argv[0])
       -symbols is a tag used      (argv[1])
       adder.asm is the input file (argv[2])
```

So once opened I should be able to grab text out of this file, and it's not a problem with the file as far as I believe, it was working earlier.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

FILE *fp;
FILE *fp_out;

void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int mode;

    if (strcmp(argv[1], "-symbols") == 0)
    {
        fp = fopen(argv[2], "r");
        mode = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        fp_out = fopen(argv[2], "w");
        mode = 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the C++ tag? This is C.

Comment: Not really, in C, it would be `int main`.

Comment: @DanielFischer Just as in C++

Comment: Do you actually test that the `fopen()` call succeeds?

Comment: @Angew Yes, but I didn't say it were C++.

Comment: "diamonds with question marks in them" means invalid characters, usually. Can you look at adder.asm with xxd or so to check what kind of bytes are in there?

Comment: Thanks for not posting any of the relevant code. That's really helpful to us, and you.

Comment: Please include the code of reading the file and printing the value

Comment: I swear whenever I post a question on this website there are always such uptight people giving responses.  I gave the C++ tag because I have found that they share many similarities especially with regards to I/O thus someone with experience in C++ would possibly be suited to help.

Comment: @Jim Balter I'm sorry this is not relevant enough for you, if I knew what the relevant code that was causing the problem was than I wouldn't  be asking for assistance on here.

Comment: And finally, I'm not sure how to go about testing if fopen() succeeds.  I was using fopen before and it was working just fine processing the text file, so I have a hard time thinking that the problem lies in the text file.  As for code of reading the file I was simply storing fgetc(fp) into a character and attempting to print it, only to receive the previously mentioned values in return

Comment: I'm not trying to be an asshole, please understand that my experience level may be low enough to the point that what I believe to be a valid question may sounds stupid to you.  If there is anything else I can provide that you think will help any of you figure this out I will do what I can. Thanks!

Comment: You don't know how to go about testing if fopen succeeds despite the manual page telling you and there being thousands upon thousands of examples, tutorials, and books that can show you? As for relevance, you say you place printf statements but you haven't shown them; nor, most relevantly, have you shown the statements where you read the data you print -- jaux told you that above, so why are you asking again? If you want to be helped here, do not whine about "uptight" people and make ridiculous excuses. We aren't psychic -- provide a complete program that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the following line  right after the open section and add `#include <errno.h>` to the beginning.

```
printf("%p, %p, %d\n", fp, ftp_out, errno);
```

If the `fp` is null then there is some problem opening the file. If you do not check the return value, you can read from a wrong buffer. Maybe there is some permission problems (or whatever). Also if `errno != 0` you have a problem. Check with `perror <num>` the errno value in command line (or see `perror(3)` function).

Comment: Alright thanks for the suggestion! I'll try that out in a few minutes and let you know what I get!

Comment: There's no need to print anything unless fp or fp_out is NULL, and if it isn't, the value of errno is undefined, so `errno != 0` is meaningless. And perror or strerror(errno) should be used, not just printing out a raw errno. Finally, we don't even know if the OP ever read any data, or how, or how it was printed. (We also only have the OP's word for it that adder.asm contains text; given how the command line is being parsed, the file may well have been taken to be an output file and overwritten at some point.)

Comment: @Jim Balter: You are right in most point. Actually `errno` value is never undefined, but it contains the value of the last error, or zero if no such happened, or the value the programmer set it. The best would be if the prog checked the return value of every open and print the error, if null. But the suggestion is a first step to localize the problem.

Comment: @GasperGulotta: I'm happy if I could help. Could you share what you have found?